# How to activate loader page while running selenium code in python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am creating a python flask web application with selenium in the backed I want to disable my webpage when the selenium driver is running to prevent user activity

I am using this code

```
<div id="disabler">
    <div class="text-center">
        <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/disabler.gif')}}">
        <p id="preloader-text">Running Automated Test</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function loader(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#disabler").fadeOut()
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using new tab every time then it is not possible to hide. You can just put always on top feature for chosen window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a predefined jQuery UI called jQuery Block UI

Or simply add a division that will block the body and will fade out when the body is loaded.

```
<div id="div">
    <h1>Please Wait..</h1>
</div>
```

jQuery will be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div").fadeOut()
  });
```